# TypeScript: auto-generated dynamic function names

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have some dynamically generated function names in TypeScript. The only way I can use them now is to cast my objects to `<any>`. Ex.: `<any>myInstance.getDataA()`. These functions are dynamically generated based on some rules. Based on the same rules I'd like to generate type-definitions for my `class`es, but I can not make it work.

**original.ts**

```
abstract class Original {

    dynamics = ['getData', 'setData'];

    constructor() {
        // I create functions here dynamically
        this.dynamics.forEach((key) => {
            this[key + this.info] = () => null;
        });
    }

    get info() {
        return 'X';
    }
}
```

**my-class.ts**

```
class MyClass extends Original {
    get info() {
        return 'A';
    }
}
```

**my-other-class.ts**

```
class MyOtherClass extends Original {
    get info() {
        return 'B';
    }
}
```

**something.ts**

```
const myInstance = new MyClass();
console.log(myInstance.getDataA()); // TS2339: Property getDataA does not exist on type: 'MyClass'

const myOtherInstance = new MyOtherClass();
console.log(myInstance.getDataB()); // TS2339: Property getDataB does not exist on type: 'MyClass'
```

I would like to automatically generate a definition file to define these  dynamic properties.

Ex.:

**my-class.def.ts**

```
 declare interface MyClass {
    getDataA;
    setDataA
 }

 //my-other-class.def.ts
 declare interface MyClass {
    getDataB;
    setDataB
 }
```

But I can not find a syntax for my definition files to make it work. Pls ask me if I was not clear, and pls help if you have any idea!

Comment: Are there more properties ? Or just one ? Because for just one it's not worth the trouble ..

Comment: there are a lot. I kept it simple for the example

Comment: The biggest problem is that we can't perform string manipulations in mapped types, so if `getInfo` returns a string literal type `A`, we can't create a property named `getDataA`

Comment: It actually work, I have the `getDataA` function, but I have to cast my instance to `any` if I'd like to call it.

Comment: I'm sure it works if you cast to any, I was saying that you can't perform this mutation in the type system

Comment: are you set on having a method `getDataA` / `setDataA` for each field ? we can write a type safe version for `getData('A')`/ `setData('A', value)` where `A` is validated to be what is returned by the `info` property

Comment: this is why I need the definition to generate

Comment: i would like to have my functions in autocomplete.

Comment: You would get autocomplete with `getData(key)` as well, you would get a completion list of the possible keys. Are you open to the idea of using the compiler API to generate the definitions ? This can be done but it implies writing an external tool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173759/discussion-between-titian-cernicova-dragomir-and-adam).

Comment: You can simply write one nodejs script to read your files from xml/js/ts or anything and you can generate some output typescript file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Edit for 4.1

Using [Template literal types and mapped type 'as' clauses](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) we can now do concatenate strings in the type system and create a class that has these properties created dynamically.

```
function defineDynamicClass<T extends string[]>(...info: T): {
    new (): {
        [K in T[number] as `get${Capitalize<K>}`]: () => unknown
    } & {
        [K in T[number] as `set${Capitalize<K>}`]: (value: unknown) => void
    } & {
        info: T
    }
} {
    return class {
        get info () {
            return info;
        }
    } as any
}
class MyClass extends defineDynamicClass('A', 'B', 'ABAB') {
}
let s =new MyClass();
s.getA();
s.getABAB();
s.setA("")
s.info;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=16&pln=6&pc=10#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKbBmVARAnmAQwFsYIBhAGwIGdqAeAFUVQA8pUxlrFqoAnTAHMA2gF0AfAAoAdLMzA4ALkQMAlMoDeAKES7EWAO6JJ6xNr0XEwgNKJMK4WBBEARqj6jENRAANBqKAASDTICAAcYKAIKGAAvVDprcQBfH1FlE0QAXnFEcABrMDgDMB09ZMQAMjMyyytbewZHZzcPL24fagDg0IiomPjElLSMgDdokFRlAqKS1Wzc0bgYZFrECurzOrswBWUGNeStCq3dPgCQPiQIKloa7cR-KB2FY3nTh8RzqEukeTgANxrCxHEHtLxgXDHLQ3GjcACyuEocOYbA4XBQ6EwOHwxFIyNokgA5ABBIkAGkQRIAQhSqSTqQyie9oRQAjxsoZEIiCdQTEDqNIniT+VpBcLGdTRYKulARQAieWqMXSf4AoA)

#### Before 4.1

### The within language approach

There is no way to do this within the type system, since we can't perform string manipulation on string literal types. The closest you can get, without external tools, is to create `get/set` methods that take a string literal type, that will be of the same as that returned by the `getInfo` method.

```
function stringLiteralArray<T extends string>(...v: T[]){ return v;}

abstract class Original {
    get(name: this['info'][number]) {
        return null;
    }

    set(name: this['info'][number], value: any) {
        return null;
    }

    get info() : string[]{
        return [];
    }
}

class MyOtherClass extends Original {
    get info() {
        return stringLiteralArray('A', 'B', 'ABAB');
    }
}
class MyClass extends Original {
    get info() {
        return stringLiteralArray('C', 'D', 'DEDE');
    }
}

let s =new MyClass();
s.get('A') // error 
s.get('C') // ok
```

While this approach is not 100% what you want, form our previous discussions the aim was to have full code-completion for the methods, and this approach achieves this. You get errors if you pass in the wrong value and you get a completion list for the string:

[image]

### The compiler API approach

A second approach would be to create a custom tool that uses the typescript [compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) to parse the ts files, look for classes derived from `Original` and generates interfaces containing the methods (either in the same file or a different file) , if you are interested in this I can write the code, but it's not trivial, and while the compiler API is stable I don't think the compiler team takes as much care with backward compatibility as they do with the language (in fact this is the exact statement they make in the documentation page).

If you are interested in such a solution, let me know and I can provide it, but I advise against it.

Comment: Isn't there a more elegant solution here now as we have Template Literal Types in the latest TS versions?

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Yes we can do better now

Comment: Thanks for the update. Are you sure the new example is correct? I'm getting the following error on the playground TS2344: Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.   Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'.     Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar Wops made a last minute change and didn't notice I broke the example. Works now

Comment: Seems to be ok now. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to have them declared as method types rather than as properties that have a lambda assigned to them?

Comment: @AvinKavish In the type system no. You will see them as function fields, rather than methods. Most of the time this should not matter, except for variance (but even that can be hacked around if you need to, search for 'typescript bivariancehack'). At runtime, it's up to you if you put those functions on the instance or on the prototype (making them more like methods)