# Typescript dynamic class functions from generics

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to do something like

```
class C<R extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  [K extends keyof R](param: R[K]) {
    console.log(K, param); // have access to both key and value
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with typescript?

Currently I have something like

```
class C<R extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  f<K extends keyof R>(k: K, param: R[K]) {
    console.log(k, param);
  }
}
```

and I want to see if I can get rid of the `f` since it's redundant/semantically not useful in my use case.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026068/typescript-auto-generated-dynamic-function-names) post, but it only generates the names and not the implementations of the functions.

Comment: What's the use case behind this

Comment: Right now I basically have `class C<...> { f<K extends keyof R>(k : K, v: R[K]) {...} } ` but it's a little redundant for the user to write `c.f(k, v)` every time, when they could write `c.k(v)`, especially because they keys are meant to be names of functions (the use case is sort of like RPC)

Comment: Wouldn't there be name collisions with other methods of the class? I'm starting to think a class is not right for this...

Comment: There are the only functions I want to define for the class, but I'm open to alternatives other than a class

Comment: Yeah so this shouldn't be a class! I'd make it a generic function which would be much easier to implement and use. Something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmBZTUAWcAJgM4DyARgFabQA8ASopgB5SZimIO1wBOROiSh8YYAOYAaROHRg4AdzAA+ZQAo+vAQC5uASl0BvALAAoRBcQBtANKIxiLAE84wbgF1dagA6o+qZF0GW3c9RABeZRkwOUUwAG4zAF9EE3NLAHoM+2RvABtMZA4oFEwAQjNLRE0oED4kMBA8vIrTJKA) perhaps?

Comment: I do want to store some variables/state in the class though. Also name collisions aren't a big deal because it's more meant for a few internal use cases. This isn't a super must have feature, it's moreso nice syntactic sugar, and I'm just wondering if its possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244236/discussion-between-simon-berens-and-kellys).

Comment: You can write a `Proxy` but it's not pretty, [see here](https://tsplay.dev/mAy01m).  Would that approach meet your needs, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep that looks like exactly what I want!

Comment: If you don't mention me via "@jcalz" then Stack Overflow is not guaranteed to let me know.  I'll write something up when I get a chance, though.

Comment: @jcalz I tried adapting your solution to my use case, but I couldn't get it to work. In my case, I don't just have one function `f`, I also have another function `g`, and the generic `C` takes actually has 2 `Record`s corresponding to `f` and `g` respectively. The problem is in the `get(t, k, r)` function I need to be able to decide which function to call; is this still possible? See [here](https://shorturl.at/sJ347) for my attempt.

Comment: Ugh, I'm partway through writing an answer and now you change the scope of the question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it would impact the solution until now :( I'm still happy to give an upvote/accept an answer for the original question

Comment: Well, my plan is to answer your question as it is asked, since that's what I've spent my time and effort on.  If you want to open a new question with the new requirement maybe I can look at it.  If you change this question to include that I can't promise anything.

Comment: You're going to need some runtime artifact that lets you figure out if a key belongs to `f` or `g`.  In practice, presumably `C` actually gets constructed with some data structure with the appropriate keys.  (I mean, if `f()` and `g()` are supposed to be able to produce arbitrary responses from arbitrary inputs then you probably need to pass those functions in).  Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKqZgN) is just an example; perhaps with a [mre] that demonstrates an actual use case I could suggest something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to call your "current" class `C<R>`:

```
class C<R extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  f<K extends keyof R>(k: K, param: R[K]) {
    console.log(k, param);
  }
  z = 1; // example of some other property of C
}
```

and we can plan to define a new class `D<R>` in terms of it that behaves how you want.   The idea will be that `D` in some sense extends `C`... so that every property of `C` is also a property of `D` (I've added an extra property for that reason), but `D<R>` will also have all the properties from `R` and will dispatch them to the `f` method of `C`.  That is, `new D<{a: string}>().a("hello")` should act the same as `new C<{a: string}>().f("a", "hello")`.

---

TypeScript will only allow you to declare `class`es or `interface`s with "statically known" keys.  Since `R` is a generic type parameter, then `keyof R` is not "statically known" so the compiler won't let you just use a `class` statement directly for this purpose.  Instead, you can describe the type of your `D<R>` class and then use something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to claim that some constructor has the right type.

It will look like

```
type D<R extends Record<string, unknown>> =
  C<R> & { [K in keyof R]: (param: R[K]) => void };

const D = ... as new <R extends Record<string, unknown>>() => D<R>;
```

where the stuff in `...` is the implementation.  So this will work, but it's somewhat ugly (since it forces you to write out the type explicitly) and error prone (since the compiler can't verify type safety here).

---

Next, you can't *implement* a `class` directly that will work this way.  If you have an instance `i` of your desired class `D<R>`, and you call `i.k(x)` where `"k"` is in `keyof T`, you want the instance to dispatch the call to something like `f("k", x)`.  Unless you have a list of all possible keys of `R` at runtime somewhere, you can't make real methods for all of them on the prototype of `D`.  That implies the methods of `D` need to have dynamic names, and that's not something a `class` normally does.

If you want dynamic property names in JavaScript, you will want to use [a `Proxy` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which lets you write [a `get()` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) to intercept all property gets.  If you make the `D` class constructor return a `Proxy` then a call to `new D()` will produce such a proxy (normally you don't return anything from class constructors, but if you do then `new` will give you the returned thing instead of `this`).

So here's one way to do it:

```
const D = class D {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(new C(), {
      get(t, k, r) {
        return ((typeof k === "string") && !(k in t)) ?
          (param: any) => t.f(k, param)
          : Reflect.get(t, k, r);
      }
    });
  }
} as new <R extends Record<string, unknown>>() => D<R>
```

If `k` is a key already present in the `C` instance, then you'll get the property at that key (hence [the `Reflect.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get) call).  Otherwise, you get a callback function which dispatches its parameter to the `f()` method of the `C` instance.

Note that this only works if you can correctly identify which properties should get dispatched to `f()` at runtime.  In this example, we are sending everything which isn't already a property of `C`.  If you have a need for some more complicated dispatching logic, you will need to write that logic yourself somewhere, probably in the form of a bunch of hard-coded property keys.  But that's out of scope for the question as asked.

So that might work, but again... it's unusual (`Proxy` and a `return` in a constructor is not best practice) and error-prone ( did I implement it right? ).

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const d = new D<{ a: string, b: number, c: boolean }>();

d.a("hello") // "a", "hello"
d.b(123); // "b", 123
console.log(d.z.toFixed(2)) // 1.00
```

Yay, it worked.  But I'm not sure it's worth the complexity and fragility of the code just to save a caller a few keystrokes.  Personally I'd rather keep the code simple and clean and make people write `c.f("a", "hello")` instead of `d.a("hello")`.  But it's up to you.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCA8AlaBTAHgFxQOwCY0RWAHsAnXeCDUgS2wHMAaaAV2wGttiB3bAPj7QA3gFgAUNGgAzeAGlUmHPmjsUAT2JToiPgAp2ALmizmABzCkwAWyOIA2rIC6ASmHjJkktgjEQKAHQgxPT6ZhbWzgDc7tAAvjEAXtAAvNAAjJHQAPRZCtamftCa0D5WKEUYABYopNCmpMSmNRhqRVqw4vFi4i1N0AAiSApYeAREZBRUtAzMbJw8-ILJMQg60ABkwtAO0HQq6sWIjka65pY22g4uKYIAbsQ0uHHR3WJeVAMp0KCQMP1uEm+xG81BYwAwZF0rlEgMkpBQGBYpGw0GwKG40AACg00GpdGiMbAocwYR4PPQEboMMx2MxSNCYmS4QikSjdFS1E1iuwUslUgAiKZ0ej81zrTYAQn0uxRGGcrgA-IymZJTuELmBsGpXMlBBh-FJQnV1c5lSrbCgpH5wf4KRgqTS6VEzXFlbFnYCurFoJBUejoEN0CNlIQSORKNRhbMOFxeAIoTcBkg+OJxO8MNAnqkCUmhD6jEKZtAAEZGbAsKzFmrMYBGYvEXwoTVxPQe8S4fxgXT86ogIKi7K5flgfnMHsoPvEfnt-zF3RpABMAGYooPoPzi6P0su08CfH5AsFdB2Ev4IQAxGhoFC4XQL+VrtL+AAMz-EQA)